# What should be written to fixed frame, rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, fixed-frame

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I read rviz/UserGuide but I still don't understand what does fixed frame means. In my rviz `map` is implicitly there. In some tutorial they add `/camera_depth_optical_frame`. Now I am playing some bag file which publics topic `/base_scan [sensor_msgs/LaserScan]` and rviz gives me global status error: `Fixed Frame [map] does not exist`. So what should be written in the fixed frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222691/what-should-be-written-to-fixed-frame,-rviz/) by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The fixed frame is what you consider not moving in the world, i.e., fixed. It is, what rviz projects all data into. For your example, you might just choose the frame that the laser is published in. However, if it is attached to a moving base, this should be a frame in the world, e.g., odom or map (if these are available).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0